# How do I add a shortcut key to Eclipse 3.2 Java plug-in to build the current project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.2

One of the few annoying things about the Eclipse Java plug-in is the absence of a keyboard shortcut to build the project associated with the current resource.  Anyone know how to go about it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the Preferences dialog box, under the General section is a dialog box called "Keys". This lets you attach key bindings to many events, including Build Project.

Answer (score 8):

You can assign a keyboard binding to *Build Project* doing the following

1. Open up the Keys preferences, Window> Preferences >General>Keys
2. Filter by type Build Project
3. Highlight the binding field.

You can then choose the binding you want

i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>,

Answer (score 1):

I believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is already configured for this by default.  Just need to have an edit window with focus.