# Eclipse CTRL+A, CTRL+E go to beginning go to end of line

Tags: eclipse, macos, shortcut

I searched and was very surprised that I can't find a possibility to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> work. So I can jump to the beginning or end of the line. I'm working on a Mac and don't have Pos1 or <kbd>Home</kbd> Button on my keyboard.

I'm pretty used to it, because everywhere I need it, it exists, not so in eclipse.

Comment: check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168426/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-key-to-eclipse-3-2-java-plug-in-to-build-the-current-pro) may it will help you

Comment: On a modern Mac keyboard, The Fn+Up/Down/Left/Right key combinations are substitutes for the PC PgUp/PgDn/Home/End keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set custom keys in eclipse - just make sure that the keys you assign are not already assigned to different actions.
e.g.

1. enter "ctrl+a" into the filter field and "unbind" the shortcut from all actions that you don't need
2. select action you want ("line start"), put cursor in "Binding" field and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Already did that, but was searching for "begin", "beginning", "go to". Thank you for the exact action name!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not set any custom keys... Ctrl E and Ctrl A were broken out-of-the-box

Answer (score 6):

Enter <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>--></kbd>). this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Another option I found was:

1. going to preferences
2. to general -> Editors -> keys
3. from Scheme select Emacs
4. Sorry I tried to post a pic, but apparently I need more points...

Answer (score 0):

Home (goes to beginning of the line),End(goes to end of the line) works for me )

Comment: are you using Eclipse in OSX?