# Eclipse shortcut to end of line and beginning of line

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the eclipse shortcut to move the cursor to the beginning of line or end of line'?

In vim I use `'0'` and `'$'` respectively in normal mode. The closest I have found is `Shift+end` and `Shift+Init` which does move the cursor, but also selects the whole line.

Comment: you can also set your own:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047627/eclipse-ctrla-ctrle-go-to-beginning-go-to-end-of-line

Comment: or install vi wrapper for eclipse: http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/ so you have all your vi commands available

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`End` key to move on end of the line, `Home` key to move on beggining of line.

Same for NetBeans and IntellijIDEA.

Answer (score 27):

For Mac people:

Goto start of line:  `command <-` (command and left arrow key)

Goto end of line:    `command ->` (command and right arrow key)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, for any editor including Eclipse, we can use following:

Go to beginning of line: `Fn <-`

Go to end of line: `Fn ->`

As mentioned in other answers, we can use `Home` and `End` keys as well for this purpose.

Comment: when trying to bind the Fn key eclipse is not reacting/recognizing that key. idk why