# Eclipse "add unimplemented methods" shortcut

Tags: eclipse, inheritance, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse IDE to add unimplemented methods when inheriting an abstract method from a superclass? It's kinda annoying to always have to click on the class name to do it. Thank you

Comment: Ctrl-comma/Ctrl-period to navigate errors, Ctrl-1 to quickfix.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> should work

Also, you could try to [create your single key bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168426/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-key-to-eclipse-3-2-java-plug-in-to-build-the-current-pro) from these combinations

Comment: @TadasDavidsonas Only if the cursor is active on the `class` line. The `Ctrl + .` goes to the `class` line wherever you are on the file.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Mac, you may use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to iterate to the error line and then <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>1, then Enter</kbd> to add unimplemented methods.

Answer (score 0):

First select the className using doubleclick on class name or Ctr+.
then Ctrl+1+enter

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Then

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>